# Inkscape - create SVG with white backgrond

Tags: inkscape, svg

ALL,

I needed an SVG for my program so I started playing with the inkscape (this software was recommended to me by my *nix distro).

I installed the latest one in their repository and was able to successfully create a test SVG, which was successfully loaded inside my program. However:

In the Inkscape I see a `white` background.

In my program the background is transparent.

Is there a way to have a `white` background in my SVG? It means to represent a a piece of white paper, so it needs to be `white`.

TIA!

EDIT:

Below is the screenshot of what I'm looking at:

[image]

I understand that there is a background inside the thin black lines square. I also understand that it is displayed white by default. And I don't want to touch it.

What I do want to change is the background inside the thick black lines and inside the circle to represent a piece of paper with the magnifying glass over its bottom right corner.

Now all I did there is to create a drawing of that paper and the magnifying glass. I didn't do anything else.

(Figured picture worth 1000 words so put it there for clarification).

EDIT 2:

As you can see the `Fill` color of the circle in the magnifying glass is `WHITE` (255, 255, 255), but in my program it still shows up as transparent. So the background of the inkscape does not matter - an SVG will be made transparent.

How do I overcome this?

[image]

Comment: Not an Inscape user but can't you simply put a white filled rectangle behind whatever your subject is to represent your paper ?

Comment: @Kyle, I suspect the SVG `inkscape` does not understand the white color and will use it to indicate transparency. OTOH, I have no idea how to do that - I'm not a graphic designer..

Comment: There re lots of really good Inkscape users on this forum- hopefully one will have a solution or explanation for you.

Comment: Note.. a white filled rectangle is **not** the same as the white background of the work area. have you **tried** using a white filled rectangle as @Kyle suggests? or are you merely guessing that it would be the same as the standard work area, since that's white? A rectangle **will** work in most applications.

Comment: @Scott, please see my edit for clarification.

Comment: I think @BillyKerr addressed the issues with your construction in comments under his answer. You appear to have a collection of disjointed, separated, path segments. That will rarely lead to a solid SVG file.

Comment: @Scott, I will see if I can make it a one path...

Comment: @Scott, I made a second edit. Can you take a look?

Comment: what is "my program"?? Also *that* circle is most likely part of a *compound shape*... meaning regardless of its color, it's set to "punch out" of the surrounding shape. I'd encourage you to create a *new document* and draw a simple, rudimentary, white-filled circle, save as SVG... the circle will be white. I believe, your entire issue is the artwork construction.

Comment: [A simple white circleSVG image](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/49vquxmn/4/) (svg created in Illustrator, but Inkscape should be no different)

Comment: @Scott, I'm writing a C++ program. It is using a standard toolbar control. When I place this SVG on that toolbar I don't see white color. I see a color of the toolbar color, which means that the SVG is transparent. In regards to that circle - I made it by clicking on the circle icon and then clicking where the center is and dragging the mouse until it hits the little handle in the bottom right corner. It is not part of any compound object.

Comment: Then this is out of scope -- I can only assume something in your custom application is not coded correctly to detect alpha in an SVG.

Comment: @Scott, it uses `nanosvg` for parsing...  I ll check with my sources as well.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, there is no background in an SVG, or in vector graphics more generally speaking. The reason for this is that SVGs are used for graphics on the web, and the background of the web page will become the background you see displayed, below the SVG graphic itself.

By default, Inkscape documents are usually set up to display a white page background, however this is not part of the SVG, it's just a convention Inkscape uses for display purposes. There is no actual physical background there.

However, you can create a rectangle the same size as the page and set the fill to white and stroke to none, then send to the bottom of the stack.  You can use snapping to get the rectangle to fit exactly to the page, or select the rectangle, and do *Edit > Resize Page to Selection*.

I have the Inkscape document set to display a checked background here (you can do this in the Document Properties) rather than the default white, so you can see what is going on.

[image]

Comment: please see my OP edit for clarification..

Comment: @Igor - hmm then not a rectangle, do the same but draw a shape with the Bézier tool, and fill it white, send to the bottom. Same process really. It's a shame the page outline is not just one shape, then you could have just changed the fill - instead you have separate lines which is not ideal.

Comment: what do you mean by `page outline is not just one shape`? Also, as far as I understand I need to draw the the same page shape with the white color inside and send it to the bottom. Now the question is - how do I do that?

Comment: @Igor You use the Bezier tool, or start with a square/rectangle, do Path > Object to Path, add some nodes with the Edit Paths by nodes tool, delete any extra nodes, adjust the Bézier handles, add a Stroke, set a Fill.  This is all really basic stuff. I suggest you do some tutorials first. There are lots on line. Youtube is good. Search for "Logos by Nick" - an excellent channel with tons of Inkscape tutorials.

Comment: @Igor Also by "one shape" I mean a closed path (a shape that is joined all the way round), not individual lines. That is how you make a shape fillable in Inkscape - again this is basic functionality in all vector image editing software, not just Inkscape.

Comment: I thought that this is the way to do it. As I said - I'm not a graphic designer. I will try to see if I can make it one shape.

Comment: I made a second edit. Can yo take a look? Also I'm trying to see how do I make a polygon as I want (not a square), but all videos/tutorials on the YouTube are about the standard shapes from inkscape. Can you point me to the one I need? I want to make a shape like that in my OP... Thx.

Comment: @Igor Use the Bézier tool to make a shape.  I don't know why your software isn't showing fills. Perhaps it isn't rendering the SVG properly. No idea why. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want to achieve, why just not use the fill property just like this?

```
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512">
<path style="fill:#fff;stroke:#1a1a1a;stroke-width:20" d="M 97.375,55.5332 C 87.8715,55.5332 80,65.3986 80,77.4551 V 352.416 c 0,6.022 1.9611,11.569 5.1094,15.631 c 3.1482,4.061 7.5088,6.648 12.2676,6.648 h 89.996 h 89.996 c 4.765,0 8.985,-2.594 11.983,-6.658 c 2.997,-4.064 4.8,-9.607 4.8,-15.621 V 77.4551 c 0,-6.0197 -1.805,-11.477 -4.804,-15.4512 c -3,-3.9742 -7.221,-6.4707 -11.979,-6.4707 H 232.492 H 141.66 Z"/>
<path style="fill:#1a1a1a" d="m 119.255,154.458 h 67.821 v 24.415 h -67.821 z"/>
<path style="fill:#1a1a1a" d="m 119.255,300.949 h 152.209 v 24.415 H 119.255 Z"/>
<path style="fill:#1a1a1a" d="m 119.255,252.119 h 92.129 v 24.415 h -92.129 z"/>
<path style="fill:#1a1a1a" d="m 117.085,104.559 h 67.821 v 24.415 h -67.821 z"/>
<path style="fill:#1a1a1a" d="m 117.085,202.22 h 78.116 v 24.415 h -78.116 z"/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke:#1a1a1a;stroke-width:20" d="m 333.191,362.602 c 5.769,-10.076 8.779,-21.28 8.779,-32.568 c 0,-36.624 -29.767,-66.433 -66.307,-66.433 c -36.54,0 -66.307,29.809 -66.307,66.433 c 0,36.623 29.767,66.432 66.307,66.432 c 11.664,0 23.203,-3.219 33.488,-9.365"/>
<path style="fill:#1a1a1a;stroke:#1a1a1a;stroke-width:20" d="m 309.151,387.101 l 35.286,35.788 c 0.794,0.794 1.923,1.296 3.052,1.296 c 1.129,0 2.258,-0.46 3.052,-1.296 l 18.103,-18.312 c 1.672,-1.714 1.672,-4.39 0,-6.062 l -35.453,-35.913 z"/>
</svg>
```

This way you add white color to the sheet of paper and black to the magnifying glass handle, so the icon will keep a transparent background just as the glass but the sheet would be white.

[image: This way you add white color to the sheet of paper and black to the magnifying glass handle, so the icon will keep a transparent background just as the glass but the sheet would be white.]

[image]